# Where do I find the c readline library in ubuntu?

Tags: c, ubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS and I've done:

`sudo apt-get install libreadline6`

Yet vs code doesn't recognize the
`#include <readline/readline.h>` or
`#include <readline/history.h>`

And calling make with:

`-Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -lreadline`

Gives me `readline/readline.h: No such file or directory`

What am I missing? Where is the library located?

Comment: It's not difficult to find - `find /usr -name \*readline\* -ls` if it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the development package: `libreadline-dev`. You've only installed the runtime package (and it does not include header files since those aren't needed in runtime).

```
$ sudo apt install libreadline-dev
...
```

Check what you got from the `libreadline-dev` package (the files you missed are marked with `*`):

```
$ dpkg -L libreadline-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/include
/usr/include/readline
/usr/include/readline/chardefs.h
/usr/include/readline/history.h                    *
/usr/include/readline/keymaps.h
/usr/include/readline/readline.h                   *
/usr/include/readline/rlconf.h
/usr/include/readline/rlstdc.h
/usr/include/readline/rltypedefs.h
/usr/include/readline/tilde.h
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhistory.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/readline.pc
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/info
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhistory.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so
/usr/share/doc/libreadline-dev
```

The output from `pkg-config --cflags --libs readline` will then give you the necessary include path options, defines and link options (taken from the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/readline.pc` listed above). Possible output:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs readline
-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -lreadline
```

Then compile and link:

```
$ gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs readline) -lhistory -Wall -Wextra ...
```